# java.rmi.UnmarshalException:Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4...etc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm work with Java RMI Project. I'm trying to insert data into a table in database in mysql server but I have this issue:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is:      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Why does this error occurs?

Comment: There seems to be a ClassNotFound exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. Check why that class is not found.

Comment: It sounds like you are marshalling exception over RMI, and your client doesn't have the MySQL Connector/J library to unmarshall the exception. The proper solution would likely be to prevent these exceptions from going over RMI from the server to your client, but use an exception type shared by both your client and server (and make sure not to set causes).